# Compile F# program in Linux using command line

Tags: c, linux, f#, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop

With C, I can write a program with a generic text editor (i.g. nano) and compile it in the Lunix terminal with

```
gcc mySum.c -o mySum
```

to get a window asking for inputs and returning the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int x;
        int y;
        int sum;
        printf("Program that sums two numbers.\n\nPlease type the first one:\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Type the second one:\n");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        sum = x + y;
        printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d\n", x, y, sum);
return 0;
}
```

Can I produce the same kind of program in F#, without Visual Studio/MonoDevelopment?

I found very instructive for me working with a nude text editor, like I am doing with C. It imposes me to be more concentrated on learning, with less help by the IDE. Furthermore, a text editor (such as nano, or notepad++ or whatever) provides more flexible tools than `fsharpi` to write the progra canm. In this way, when the program is completed, I give it to the compiler in the same way I did with C in the example.

I would say by implementing the function

```
let mySum x y =
    x + y
```

with

```
fsharpc mySum.fs
```

but I fail to get how to achieve it. I found [this reference](https://vincentaube.net/f-development-without-visual-studio.html) but it is a little advanced.

Comment: Are you aware of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which runs on Linux and is not to be confused with Visual Studio. See [Getting Started with F# in Visual Studio Code with Ionide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-vscode)

Comment: @GuyCoder, I added your suggestion to my answer, thanks. It is the most barebone version of VS, I never worked with it myself, but I believe it is quite popular and excellent if you are only interested in writing code and have no need for the rest.

Comment: @Abel You should consider installing Visual Studio Code. For quick to small projects, even outside of F#, such as JS, HTML, XML, json, [DOT](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html), Prolog, assembly, Markdown, OCaml, and other things it is the go to IDE for me.

Comment: @guy, prolog? Haven't used that since university ;). Didn't know it was so versatile, will check for sure. Tx

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks for the edit!

Comment: @Abel You might also be interested in [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) and [WSL-Programs](https://github.com/ethanhs/WSL-Programs)

Comment: With regards to using WSL and editing files see: [Editing Linux files](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1319). I have been experimenting with WSL for many months now and forget that you have to understand a few things before it becomes second nature to use.

Comment: I also subscribe to the [WSL issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues?page=7&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) to see when things are fixed or updated. The last big change is that [Haskell](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/307) is now working, but you have to be on the [Fast Ring](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/831) to use it.

Comment: Of interest: [Visual Studio Code and Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL) GCC/GDB integration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39224311/1243762) Discusses setting up `sshd` to use interactive debugging.

Comment: Of interest: [Kicking off a WSL bash-based build from Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38231537/1243762)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is [FSI (F# Interactive)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/), which is called `fsharpi` on Linux / MacOS. You can also use `fsharpc`, which will compile it, but if you are just trying out, testing or scripting then the [REPL environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) that `fsharpi` gives you is probably more convenient.

An introduction for using it from Linux [can be found here](http://fsharp.org/use/linux/).

Note that you must at least have Mono installed before you can do anything with F# in Linux.

EDIT: As illustration, the program you mention in C can be expressed in a myriad of ways, here's one way (which assumes correct input, or exception, program not tested):

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let scani() =
        printfn "Give a number: "
        Console.ReadLine()
        |> Int64.Parse

    let (x, y) = (scani(), scani())
    printfn "The sum of %d and %d is %d" x y (x + y)

    // wait before returning prompt
    printfn "Hit any key to continue"
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

EDIT 2: you edited your question and expressed your wish to work with "Nano". That is an editor that I don't know. You also say that you don't want to use Mono. I don't know why that is, unless you mean MonoDevelop, because without Mono you cannot compile a .NET program on Linux.

The command you mention, `gcc mySum.c -o mySum` can be translated into a commandline variant for F#. For instance (assuming same syntax as for `fsc.exe`) (put on multiple lines for clarity):

```
fsharpc.exe 
 -o:MyProgram.exe 
 --debug:pdbonly 
 --noframework 
 --optimize+ 
 --platform:anycpu32bitpreferred 
 -r:"PathTo\FSharp.Core.dll" 
 -r:"PathTo\mscorlib.dll" 
 -r:"PathToYourReferencedOtherDlls\SomeClassLib.dll 
 -r:"PathTo\System.Core.dll" 
 -r:"PathTo\System.dll"
 --target:exe 
 --warn:3 
 file1.fs file2.fs file3.fs
```

Many of these options can possibly be left out, but this is a valid commandline, taken from Visual Studio.

I would, however, suggest to use an editor that is preconfigured to run F# programs, that has a REPL integrated, as well as a debugger, syntax coloring, live type information (very important!) and other intellisense features, which you get with Visual Studio (the [VS Code edition runs on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and has an excellent editor, courtesy to *Guy Coder* for reminding me) and possibly some other F# enabled editors out there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me to better define the problem. I frequently use `fsharpi`. I would like to use the more flexible tools provided by a text editor, such as nano, to write the program. Once the program is completed, give it to the compiler in the same way I did with C.

Comment: Any text editor is ok, actually. Nano is just the one I use more often :)

Comment: @Worice, I see you edited your question. While I don't understand your motivation from _not_ wanting to use Visual Studio or MonoDevelop, I have tried to give an example commandline (a bit more wielded than necessary perhaps).

Comment: It is an excellent example Abel, thank you. I am a newie coder. I just found very instructive for me working with a nude text editor, like I am doing with C. It imposes me to be more concentrated on learning, with less help by the IDE. Didactic purposes, I could say.

Comment: @Worice You should have, and should put that into the question. e.g `I just found very instructive for me working with a nude text editor, like I am doing with C. It imposes me to be more concentrated on learning, with less help by the IDE.`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @GuyCoder.

Comment: @Worice, good to know. I'd personally rather learn the language, the intricacies of all its tools are of less interest and only distract. But that's only my perspective, everybody learns in its own way ;). Glad it helped!