# Visual Studio doesn't see all files in System32

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file, post-build-event, post-build

I set some post-build commands in Visual Studio 2017 that should allow me to run a program that I currently have in System32 (wsl.exe). However, Visual Studio doesn't see the program.

I tried to set the command to `dir C:\Windows\System32\` to see all the files it could list, and in fact it doesn't list over a 1'000 files out of the around 4'600 files I have there, including the `wsl.exe` file I'm trying to run. The number of files show up correctly when running the same command in the command prompt.

I've tried to run `whoami` as the post-build command, and it returns the same user as if I run the same command in the command prompt.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does this have to do with Visual Studio?  `wsl` is the *Windows Subsystem for Linux*. It's not just any executable. You *can* run it from any folder though, as it's in the path. Just type `wsl`.

Comment: This has to do with Visual Studio because it cannot see the `wsl` file at all when executing the `dir` command with it. I know I can run it from any folder, and because it was throwing the error `"wsl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."` I've tried more steps and came to the conclusion that running `dir` in the post-build commands, it didn't show all the files in the directory. All of this while I can see the file correctly using the Windows command prompt

Comment: 1) no repro. I can see it and call it just fine 2) It has nothing to do with VS. `dir` is a command-line command. You are asking why you can't see some files in System32, without specifying what those files are. 3) What `wsl`? Does it even exist? Is it installed? Are you trying to start a Unix shell from your post-build step?

Comment: About your number 2): then how come running the `dir`command in VS does not show the wsl.exe file, while running `ls -al /mnt/c/Windows/System32` in WSL shows it, and in command prompt running `dir C:\Windows\System32\` shows it as well. For your number 3): I've clarified that in the post saying that indeed **I currently have in System32 (wsl.exe)**, so yes, it does exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kicking off a WSL bash-based build from Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38231537/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio itself is 32-bit application. As such, the OS shims the application behavior to a different view of the Windows and System32 folders.  i.e `c:\Windows\System32` in the application is actually the `c:\Windows\SysWow64` folder for 32-bit apps.  That explains why it can't see the wsl.exe binary...  Not sure what the workaround is... looking into this...

Comment: `wsl` is the Windows Subsystem for Linux. It's not missing either, running `dir wsl.exe` inside System32 works, assuming the feature is installed of course. In any case the OP shouldn't put anything in System32.

Comment: Not "putting anything in System32". WSL was automatically installed there using the Programs and Features in the Control Panel. Still, will try, @selbie

Comment: @PeterAS17 you haven't explained what you are trying to do. Or what `WSL` you refer to. I can start WSL, the Windows Subsystem for Linux, just fine by typing `wsl` in *any* console. I can see it just fine with `dir` after changing the current directory to `C:\Windows\System32`. I can also see it with `dir c:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos to clarify the output on each side:
VS shows "File not found" using the `dir c:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe`. Command prompt shows the file: `06.09.2018  15:02           114 688 wsl.exe`

Comment: @PeterAS17 your *real* question was how to run a Linux build step. This is already answered [in this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231537/kicking-off-a-wsl-bash-based-build-from-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: @selbie You're absolutely right... I didn't pay attention to the fact that VS was a 32-bit application and ignored the fact that it pointed to the SysWow64 folder. Copying and pasting the needed files for the post-build command seems to have done the job for now. Gotta search for a better workaround if any. Thanks!

Comment: [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector): "32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access."